# "Sorry no preview is available" in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, paper

I am preparing a Research paper with my guide to publish,he sent a zip file and I need to edit it,So Iam trying to open this zip file in overleaf but the display shows as shown in screenshot,I don't know why,please help me[image]

Comment: I cutted tex file from that zip file and paste it in a separate folder outside zip folder,and I open this tex file in overleaf I got code which can be compiled but the pdf generated by this code does not contain sitations , some images and some graphs.... why this happens and what will i do,I am a very beginer in the world of latex...

Comment: Does overleaf have an unzip feature? Right now you're asking overleaf to try to "show" you a zip file. Of course the viewer does not know what to do with it. It should be in the overleaf faq/help what to do when uploading a project as a zip file

Comment: Or have a look at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Uploading_a_project and see if that helps you.

Comment: You my need to download the `.zip` file (if you do not have in hand) and open a new project by uploading this file. Overleaf will identify it and upload the items included (if is is not corrupted).

Comment: I do as you say ,but it couldn't work@Cragfelt

Comment: Have you contacted Overleaf's Helpdesk? I hear their LaTeX support staff are top notch.

Comment: I contacted the staff now the problem is solved thanks to this community